Updates on central Bitbucket ScriptRunner scripts don't affect behaviour
In Bitbucket ScriptRunner you can create centralised scripts under Adminsitration > ScriptRunner > Script Editor
Those script can be used, e.g. in Administration > ScriptRunner > Merge Checks, when referencing them in the script editor within the web ui.
I face the issue that when an existing centralised script is updated, those updates don't affect the Merge Check, where this script is used. The only two ways I figured out is to

update the script within the Merge Check. Then the "whole thing" is reloaded and the updates inside the centralised script are recognised, or
restart the server or bitbucket application.

Obviously there is some kind of caching, where the overall script is only updated, when the script within the Merge Check is updated.
Interesting side note:
When I change a source script and then change the calling script within the Merge Check, the changes inside the source script have an impact. As soon as I remove the changes from the calling script (so it is the previous state again), the old version of the source script is executed again. IMHO that's a little bit lol...
My special case: I want to versionise the centralised scripts by setting up a git repository inside the file system directory, to update them all at once after implementations and/or refactoring is done. Of course I cannot fiddle around in all the places (Merge Checks, pre-hooks) when such an update occurs. It would also be bad, if I have to restart Bitbucket, just because I edited those files.
How can I enforce Scriptrunner to reload the central scripts and refresh all the effective scripts inside Merge Checks, Pre Hooks, etc. so that the changes inside the centralised script take effect?
